# How to start the latest version of k8s using minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

When a k8s cluster is created using minikube, the output indicates that an outdated version of k8s is deployed:

```
user@host ~ $ minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.6.4 cluster...
Starting VM...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://rominirani.com/tutorial-getting-started-with-kubernetes-on-your-windows-laptop-with-minikube-3269b54a226

```
user@host ~ $ minikube start --kubernetes-version="v1.7.5"
Starting local Kubernetes v1.7.5 cluster...
Starting VM...
```